# Breakpoints are not hit when debugging, Outlook Add in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I spend to resolve this issue for half of my working day but I could not find out the solution.
I am using Visual Studio 2013 and have around 10 projects in one solution.
one of them is Outlook Addin.

The Outlook refer to Debug Directory ( PROJECT_NAME/bin/Debug/AddinOutlook2013.vsto|vstoocal)

It success to show up a simple dialog ( OK ) when a button in Addin in Outlook was clicked. But when i put the break point that code, it is never hit.

**PROBLEM**

Breakpoints are not hit when debugging in Outlook Add in project.

**What I DID were :**

- Tried to this link 
  https://www.add-in-express.com/docs/net-deploying-debugging-tips.php
- Run the both window application and outlook after re-installed the
  add in.
- Enable 'Define DEBUG constant' and disable 'Optimize code'
- Set the 'Startexternal program' to the outlook application '.exe'
  path.

How can i hit the breakpoint ?

Thank you for any help and advice.

Comment: This happens to me sometimes, have you tried right clicking on the project in question and choosing ReBuild? Then run your solution as normal.

Comment: Try rebuilding and also ensure that your Solution configuration is in "Debug mode" not "Release mode".

Comment: Right click Solution and select configuration manager, It should have Configuration is "debug" for the Outlook Add in project (as the path refers to debug in your question). Now, check the platform. You can make it x86, and rebuild. I had similar problem that break points were not working on my 64 bit machine, moving to x86 from configuration manager helped me.

Comment: Resolved !!!!

jbmintib, krw12572, Mukul Varshney
Thank you for many helps. Finally i have done it !!

** How did I fix **
Set the Startup Project to Addin Project.
Then Close Outlook and then Run as Debug for the Solution.

Thank you for many helps! 
I love you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !!!!

Thank you for many helps. Finally i have done it !!

**How did I fix**

Set the Startup Project to Addin Project.
Then Close Outlook and then Run as Debug for the Solution.

Thank you for many helps!

I love you!